# Standard current and discharge current

Tags: batteries, current, current-source, constant-current

I've been looking into batterie's datasheets and don't understard what 2 of the specifications mean: continuous standard current and maximum continuous discharge current. Could someone explain this to me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post a link to the specification, which you are referring to?  That would help answer your question better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Standard discharge current** is related with **nominal/rated battery capacity** (for example 2500mAh), and **cycle count**.

If the battery is discharged with a higher current, the real available capacity will be smaller (it may be much smaller). Discharging the battery with a lower current will extend the real available capacity a little bit.

Currents higher than standard will shorten the battery life, lower will extend it (in comparison with nominal cycle count).

**Maximum continuous discharge current** is a current that will not overheat and destroy the battery, but keep in mind that discharging a battery with the maximum allowed current will reduce its battery life significantly and probably the real available capacity will be less than nominal.

Here is an example, where you can see how the battery capacity changes at different discharge currents.

[image: screenshot from datasheet]

Source: [Panasonic LC-R121R3P VRLA battery datasheet](http://www.panasonic.com/industrial/includes/pdf/Panasonic_VRLA_LC-R121R3P.pdf)

There is no information about the maximum discharge current, however it looks like that battery can be discharged with 850 mA, but then you can't use whole 1.3 Ah capacity.

Another example - Sanyo AAA Eneloop NiMh rechargeable battery:

[image: screenshot from datasheet]

[image: screenshot from datasheet]

Source: [Sanyo AAA Eneloop NiMh HR4U-TGA NiMH battery datasheet](http://us.sanyo.com/dynamic/product/Downloads/HR-4UTGA-2010-47828277.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Continuous standard current sounds like "nominal" drain current, what current does the manufacturer expect to be a typical load under ordinary usage, probably much less than the maximum.  In general you might expect this number to be something like 1/5 or 1/10 of the C rate, meaning a 5 hour or 10 hour time to fully discharge.

Maximum continuous discharge current sounds like what is the maximum drain current that will remain safe on the battery without "abusing" it and thereby shortening battery life.  Probably they state "continuous" as a way of saying DC or quasi-DC current, meaning it's OK if current spikes above the "maximum" for very short periods of time, e.g. milliseconds but not seconds at a time, especially if buffered by a large bypass capacitor.